# How to save application settings?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core

We have a UWP for Windows IoT Core, we need to save some settings, but these settings have to live even if the application is stopped or the IoT device restarted.

The code I have is the following, it works perfectly fine when the app is open, and if I switch between XAML pages, but doesn't work when the application is stopped, it's like the variable never existed.

```
static class Global
{
    public static Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings { get; set; }
    public static Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder { get; set; }
}

private void Btn_Inciar_Config_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TxtDeviceKey.Text != String.Empty || TxtDeviceName.Text != String.Empty || Txt_Humedad_Config.Text != String.Empty || Txt_Intervalo_Config.Text != String.Empty || Txt_Temperatura_Ambiente_Config.Text != String.Empty || Txt_Temperaura_Config.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =
        new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
        composite["GlobalDeviceKey"] = TxtDeviceKey.Text;
        composite["GlobalDeviceName"] = TxtDeviceName.Text;
        composite["GlobalTemperature"] = Txt_Temperaura_Config.Text;
        composite["GlobalHumidity"] = Txt_Humedad_Config.Text;
        composite["GlobalTemperatureRoom"] = Txt_Temperatura_Ambiente_Config.Text;
        composite["GlobalInterval"] = Txt_Intervalo_Config.Text;

        localSettings.Values["ConfigDevice"] = composite;
        Lbl_Error.Text = "";
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
    else
    {
        Lbl_Error.Text = "Ingrese todos los campos de configuracion";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store your settings locally you can store them as single items or as a `ApplicationDataCompositeValue` (to keep all values as a single entity) like you did. Just put the composite (or single items) in the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` container. Below a small piece of code that you can simply copy paste in an empty app and attach to 2 buttons to try out.

```
private void SaveClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =
        new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
    composite["GlobalDeviceKey"] = "Key";
    composite["GlobalDeviceName"] = "Name";
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["ConfigDevice"] = composite;
}

private void LoadClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =
        (ApplicationDataCompositeValue) ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["ConfigDevice"];
    var key = (string)composite["GlobalDeviceKey"];
}
```